# Form labels and input elements in separate div's

Tags: html, css, accessibility

we are trying to layout 3 columns of a form like the second row in the image below

[image]

The label text and form elements' can vary in size and type so it's proving difficult to align as required that works cross browser. We are trying a number of solutions and one possibility is having a separate row for the labels and a separate row for the input elements. We can then vertically align the labels to the bottom and align the input elements to the top.

Would it be enough for screen readers if we included the necessary 'for' and 'aria' attributes on the label to associate it to the input element even though the label and input element are not beside each other in the source ? Accessibility is something we must consider.

Thank you for any advice. Fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/wYdZr/5/

```
    <div class="container_12" style="background:green;">
    <div class="grid_4 lbl"   >
          <label for="firstName">TR 1 TD 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_4 lbl">
            <label for="lastName" >Bonorum Fermentum Tortor Adipiscing Pharetra</label>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_4 lbl">
            <label>Bonorum Fermentum Tortor Adipiscing Pharetra Bonorum Fermentum Tortor Adipiscing Pharetra</label>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div> 
</div>
<div class="container_12" style="background:yellow;">
    <div class="grid_4">
          <input type="text" id="firstName"/>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_4"><textarea id="lastName"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_4">
            <input type="text" id="phone" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wYdZr/6/ That fiddle will give you part of what you want, but I'm working on getting the text positioned correctly.

Comment: This: http://jsfiddle.net/wYdZr/8/ will work, but you have to have a height set on `.lbl`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and updated fiddle but all i want to know is if it's ok to place a label in a separate div to the input element it relates to !

Comment: Sorry, I went to your fiddle and it was not formatting correctly. But yes, you can do that. The label does not have to be directly beside the input. But that is best practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would it be enough for screen readers if we included the necessary 'for' and 'aria' attributes on the label to associate it to the input element even though the label and input element are not beside each other in the source ?

Yes, that’s why there is the [`for` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-label-for) in the first place.

Of course there is always the possibility that some screen reader (versions) don’t support `for`, but that should be a minority and the error would be clearly on their side.

The `for` method is also mentioned in the WCAG 2.0 technique [H44: Using label elements to associate text labels with form controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20130905/H44.html). Note that the test for this particular technique checks the position of the label:

- `label` **before** `input` (`text`, `file`, `password`), `textarea`, `select`
- `label` **after** `input` (`checkbox`, `radio`)

But this is only a requirement for this particular technique, so you don’t necessarily have to comply with it, as there are other techniques and ways to fullfil the relevant success criterions.

Answer (score -1):

You can simple use a HTML table, no divs.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/wYdZr/7/

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this doesn't answer what i asked. Tables are of course an option but surely the grid based approach is better for accessibility and screen readers ?

Comment: You're welcome! I think table is better than divs for grid viewing because it have a flexible width.

Comment: How is a table better than a div for grid viewing? A div can have a flexible width as well.